# Okta Integration WebSphere

Tags: apache, websphere, single-sign-on, okta

I have to integrate Websphere Application Server with OKTA. After googling I have configured snoop application as now I access OKTA(https://myorg.okta.com) and see the application there click there and I am logged in to the application successfully.

But my question is this at most of the tutorial after OKTA integration the url(https://washost/snoop) is mentioned for testing.

Can you please guide me which approach is right and why?

Many Thanks

Comment: The snoop servlet is a part of the Default Application that ships with WAS. Hitting the snoop servlet simply ensures that you have WAS up and running correctly. Can you clarify the rest of your question?

Comment: Yes it is.What I ma saying is that when I access the nopp directly like https://washost/snoop It Works.Snoop is also running when I It via OKTA.As I have configured the SAML TAI in websphere.

Comment: Okay, so the snoop servlet is accessible directly using the URL and using Okta. You are using Okta as an SSO provider, so I believe that is expected behaviour. What is the question here?

Comment: Is there any behavior that is unexpected ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: @XSurgent and Rama ,,,Actually things are running fine but my question is this at most of the tutorial after OKTA integration the url(https://washost/snoop) is mentioned for testing.when this URL is hit it redirects to OKTA then. In my case I access OKTA and snoop is mentioned there and things are great.

Comment: Rama Sohaib and Xsurgent,

I have googled it more and understood my issue.Actually there are two types of Web SSO.

IDP(OKTA) Initiated where the URL becomes like this https://okta.com and SP(Websphere) Initiated where URL is like this https://washost/snoop. Websphere do not support SP Initiated SSO. It only supports IDP initiated SSO.

Thanks alot guys for helping me.Since I have successfully verified OKTA Integration with snoop I can easily integrate with any custom application.

Many Thanks,

Umar

Answer (score 0):

Rama Sohaib and Xsurgent,

I have googled it more and understood my issue.Actually there are two types of Web SSO.

IDP(OKTA) Initiated where the URL becomes like this https://okta.com and SP(Websphere) Initiated where URL is like this https://washost/snoop. Websphere do not support SP Initiated SSO. It only supports IDP initiated SSO.

Thanks alot guys for helping me.Since I have successfully verified OKTA Integration with snoop I can easily integrate with any custom application.

Many Thanks,

Umar